# Memcached real memory usage

Tags: memcached

When I was checking a memcached config, i found a weird thing that i dind't get.

In the startup script, we say to memcached to use 512 mb:

```
PORT="11211" 
USER="memcached" 
MAXCONN="1024" 
CACHESIZE="512" 
OPTIONS=" -l X.X.X.X -I 20m "
```

But the result of stats slabs show that more space is used :

```
active_slabs    46 # Total number of slab classes allocated.
total_malloced  903,665741 # Total amount of memory allocated to slab pages.
```

How can this numbers be explained.

Thanks.

Comment: Could this be code + cache = 700 ?

Comment: @Marged it could be, but 264 mo of code, it's a lot i think for memcached